# Where Is color_map defined in BGL?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

[Example code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/example/bfs-example2.cpp) from BGL:

```
breadth_first_search(g, vertex(s, g), color_map(get(&VertexProps::color, g)).visitor(vis));
```

What is `color_map`, where is it defined? And where is it documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's defined as a named parameter in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp

Comment: And it appears in the documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/graph/doc/breadth_first_search.html - you need to grok the boost named parameter mechanism first tho.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the src-code I would suggest that you take a look at [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)
This remarkable tool will index the code for you and allow instant jumping the the definition/implementation of everything indexed in the src-tree.

Another approach is to use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) to search for it.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I know how to search source tree.  I've used grep, and I haven't found anything that matches what the example code is doing.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be the [two bit color map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/graph/two_bit_color_map.hpp) from that library?

Comment: The-Tiger Great, but WHY do everyone spell my name incorrectly, it's not that difficult is it? ;-)

Comment: @Fredrik: I apologize. I wasn't paying attention. :(